# How to declare weak notification

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, nsnotificationcenter, deinit

Maybe the title does not provide a good description so please read the following.

I have a notification that is set to listen to an event:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.checkIfNotificationsWereTurnedOnAfterAlertShowing), name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: UIApplication.sharedApplication())
```

Then I want to remove observer on this notification. 
I found that I need to use deinit like this:

```
deinit  { 
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification)
    print("deinit")
}
```

But the problem is that when i close the view controller, the program never executes deinit function. 
In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28202154/5999975) i found that it could be due to strong reference.

I checked many links but was not able to find how to declare a weak reference for a notification. 
So how can I declare a weak notification?

Hope my question is clear.

Looking forward for your help.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425354/what-type-of-reference-does-nsnotificationcenter-keep-for-observers-object

Comment: It is weak reference. You must have something else hanging on to it.

Comment: Refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26971415/deinit-never-called

Comment: As a rule, view controllers should add observations in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` and remove them in `viewWillDisappear` or `viewDidDisappear`. This will address almost all life-cycle issues. It is somewhat normal for view controllers to continue to exist after being taken off screen (depending on how they were displayed); however they should never be observing notifications when they are offscreen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to find the way to handle this with `deinit` so I decided to remove observer in `viewWillDisappear` which worked well for me. Suggested by [Rob Napier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97337/rob-napier) in the comment above